# Can "spill" be a noun?

Tags: vocabulary, nouns, exam-questions

I have a doubt in this question:

> Which is the odd one?
>   A) spill
>   B) soap
>   C) hand sanitizer
>   D) mouthwash

I guess it's all related to hygiene so is it "spill" because it's a verb, but I discovered it can also be a noun and mean like a drop that was spilled, as in "a spill of coffee".

In terms of liquids, only soap can be excluded.

Comment: You mixed the reasons: is **spill** the odd one because it is not about hygiene; or because **spill** is a "verb"? Note that you can get liquid soap too.

Comment: Thanks so spill is an odd because it's verb?

Comment: As you wrote, spill is a noun too. Voting to close because this is opinion-based.

Comment: "Spill" doesn't fit with the others. Seen as a verb, it doesn't fit because the others are nouns. Seen as a noun, it doesn't fit either, because it means the result of an accident, while the other three are simply personal care products. So it doesn't matter whether it's a noun or a verb.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty **soap** is also a verb.

Comment: @Weather Vane: Yes, of course you're right. So "spill" is out because it's either an accident or the result of one, while the others aren't.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: A [spill](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spill) (noun) is also a small roll or twist of paper or slip of wood for lighting a fire. Still the odd one out, since nothing to do with hygiene. A poor test or quiz question.

Comment: I agree that this is a poor test question.  *Mouthwash* can be used as a verb, so maybe *hand sanitizer* is the answer.  Or maybe it's *soap*, because that's the only choice without any repeated letters.  Or maybe it's *mouthwash*, because the other options could be related to cleaning in the kitchen.

Comment: Spill does not contain the letter 'a'; all the others do.

Comment: Quiz questions should be off topic because they're only useful to other people taking the same quiz.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the word *spill* is often used as a noun, especially when there is a major oil spill in the ocean. See [Google Search](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=oil%20spills%20effects&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart) for "oil spill." There are too many websites and articles to list here.

Let's look at the title of one academic paper: [Estimating the mortality of seabirds following oil spills: Effects of spill volume](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0025326X93901232). The unspoken admonishment to the people who let these spills happen is: *Don't spill the oil!*

Thus, the word "spill" can be used as a noun, adjective ([adjectival noun or attributive noun](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-when-nouns-act-like-adjectives/2998821.html) ), and verb:

Noun: oil *spill*

Adjective/adjectival noun: *spill* volume

Verb: *spill* the oil

I agree that "spill" is the odd one in your list of four words because it does not fit in with hygiene.

Comment: Please don't answer bad questions. Your phrases "oil spill" and "spill volume" are **noun phrases**, not an adjective **spill**.

Comment: In *spill volume*, *spill* is a noun modifying *volume*. Just because it modifies, doesn't mean it's an adjective. An easy enough mistake to make, however.

Comment: Someone rewrote the grammar rules since I was in school in the 1960s. I edited my answer according to the info I found online.